# Distribution of M objects in N container

Tags: c++, math, permutation

Given a N size array whose elements denotes the capacity of containers ...In how many ways M similar objects can be distributed so that each containers is filled at the end.
for example

```
for arr={2,1,2,1} N=4 and M=10 there comes out be 35 ways.
```

Please help me out with this question.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the sum of the container sizes. I your case 2+1+2+1 = 6 let this be P. Find the number of ways of choosing P objects from M. There are M choices for the first object, M-1 for the second, M-2 for the third etc. This gives use M * (M-1) * ... (M-p+1) or M! / (M-P)!. This will give us more states than you want for example

```
1 2 | 3 | 4 5 | 6
2 1 | 3 | 4 5 | 6
```

There is q! ways of arranging q object in q slots so we need to divide by factorial(arr[0]) and factorial(arr[1]) etc. In this case divide by 2! * 1! * 2! * 1! = 4.

I'm getting a very much larger number than 35. 10! / 4! = 151200 divide that by 4 gives 37800, so I'm not sure if I have understood your question correctly.

---

Ah so looking at the problem you need to find N integers n1, n2, ... ,nN so that n1+n2+...+nN = M and n1>= arr[1], n2>=arr[2].

Looks quite simple let P be as above. Take the first P pills and give the students their minimum number, arr[1], arr[2] etc. You will have M-P pills left, let this be R.

Essentially the problem simplifies to finding N number >=0 which sum to R. This is a classic problem. As its a challenges I won't do the answer for you but if we break the N=4, R=4 answer down you may see the pattern

```
4 0 0 0        - 1 case starting with 4
3 1 0 0        - 3 cases starting with 3
3 0 1 0
3 0 0 1
2 2 0 0        - 6 cases
2 1 1 0
2 1 0 1
2 0 2 0
2 0 1 1
2 0 0 2

1 3 0 0       -  10 cases
1 2 1 0
1 2 0 1
1 1 2 0
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 2
1 0 3 0          
1 0 2 1
1 0 1 2
1 0 0 3

0 4 0 0       - 15 cases
0 3 1 0
0 3 0 1
0 2 2 0
0 2 1 1
0 2 0 2
0 1 3 0
0 1 2 1
0 1 1 2
0 1 0 3
0 0 4 0
0 0 3 1
0 0 2 2
0 0 1 3
0 0 0 4
```

You should recognise the numbers 1, 3, 6, 10, 15.

Comment: You may have a look at the problem link for better understanding ..http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/sleeping-pills/